# AngularJS Move to nested abstract view

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ngroute

I have nested abstract view in my angular js project.
I got `Error : Cannot transition to abstract state 'main.middle'` when i move to nested abstract view.
My `html` code is as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="nesting">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-router@*" data-semver="0.2.10" src="https://rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-router/0.2.10/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="testController">
    href:
    <br /> 
    <a href="#/alpha">#/alpha</a>
    <a href="#/beta">#/beta</a>
    <a href="#/gama">#/gama</a>
    <button ng-click="moveToMiddle()">move to middle</button>
    <br />
    ui-sref:
    <br /> 
    <a ui-sref="main.middle.alpha">main.middle.alpha</a>
    <a ui-sref="main.middle.beta">main.middle.beta</a>
    <a ui-sref="main.middle.gama">main.middle.gama</a>

    <hr />
    <div ui-view=""></div>

    <script>

      'use strict';

      var $urlRouterProviderRef = null;
      var $stateProviderRef = null;

      var app = angular.module('nesting', [
        'ui.router'
      ]);

      app.config(function( $urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {

          $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/alpha');


          $stateProvider
            .state('main', {
                url: "",
                abstract: true,
                template: '<div><h3>Main</h3><div ui-view=""></div></div>',
            })
            .state('main.middle', {
                url: "",
                abstract: true,
                template: '<div><h4>Middle</h4><div ui-view=""></div></div>',
            })
            .state('main.middle.alpha', {
                url: "/alpha",
                template: '<div><h5>The leaf: {{state.name}}</h5></div>',
                controller: function ($scope, $state){
                  $scope.state = $state.current;
                },
            })
            .state('main.middle.beta', {
                url: "/beta",
                template: '<div><h5>The leaf: {{state.name}}</h5></div>',
                controller: function ($scope, $state){
                  $scope.state = $state.current;
                },
            })
            .state('main.middle.gama', {
                url: "/gama",
                template: '<div><h5>The leaf: {{state.name}}</h5></div>',
                controller: function ($scope, $state){
                  $scope.state = $state.current;
                },
            })
            ;
      });     

      app.controller('testController', function ($scope, $state) {
          $scope.moveToMiddle = function () {
             $state.go('main.middle');
          }
      })
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

When I click on `move to middle` button I got error.

How to move to abstract view?

I have referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24842495/angularjs-nested-abstract-views) but its not useful in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You never *go* to an abstract state. From the [docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views#abstract-states):

> An abstract state can have child states but can not get activated itself. An 'abstract' state is simply a state that can't be transitioned to. It is activated implicitly when one of its descendants are activated.

If you define `main.middle.alpha`, `main.middle.beta`, and `main.middle.gama` as not abstract, you can transition to those.

Comment: Then how to handle such scenarios, i have `link` to `alpha`,`beta` and `gama` in `middle`, when i click on any link, `middle` view reloaded.
(`middle` is not `abstract` in this case)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't fully understand. If you click on one of those three `ui-sref` links, they should load the corresponding child state of middle.

Comment: What scenarios? Your code above has `main.middle` as abstract.

Comment: Actual scenario : in `main` state i have link to `middle` state (not `abstract`) and in middle there are links to child states, when i click any link in `middle` middle view reloaded with child view.

Comment: You don't want `middle` to reload when you go to one of the children?

Comment: transitioning directly between the children should not reload `middle`. If `middle` is inactive, it will load if you transition directly to one of the children states.

Comment: i want exactly what you wrote, i didn't get your last comment. when i move to children for first time, it reloads middle, then its working fine. (only first time `middle` state reloaded)

Comment: What I just wrote in the comments is the regular behavior using ui-router. You need to edit/update your original question, so we can understand what your current problem is.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in angualr docs

> An abstract state can have child states but can not get activated
>   itself. An 'abstract' state is simply a state that can't be
>   transitioned to. It is activated implicitly when one of its
>   descendants are activated.

```
 app.controller('testController', function ($scope, $state) {
          $scope.moveToMiddle = function () {
             $state.go('main.middle.alpha');
          }
```

as abstract state cannot be instantiated and can't viewed. if you want to access then remove `abstract` line